# FreeNAS ZFS Kernel Panic

Tags: zfs, truenas, kernel-panic

I'm running FreeNAS 8 and my computer had a hard reset from a power outage and now every time I try to boot I get the following error message:

```
Error Message: panic: zfs_replay_acl_v0:898: unsupported condition
```

I am running ZFS with ZFS filesystem version 4, ZFS storage pool version 15. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Take a look about you hardware, what kind of controller do you have, what hard drives... etc. This is very important on FreeNAS, check out the forum of FreeNAS, maybe it helps.

Comment: If the forums don't help and the error hasn't been reported anywhere before, maybe open a [bug](https://bugs.freenas.org/) with the FreeNAS people.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the live option of the FreeBSD media(shell) and try to create a new zfspool.cache.

- http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=4185
- http://ximalas.info/2011/10/17/zfs-root-fs-on-freebsd-9-0/

I don't know how the internals of FreeNAS are, but once you could find the pool, it is just to create another zfspool.cache. Just don't forget to backup your current zfspool.cache.

Use the command `fmdump -eV` to figure out what could be the software root cause of this crash